# How can I retrieve my old Pokemon Moon save data?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I've put over 1000 hours into all pokemon games total and every single pokemon I caught was on moon. I bought the digital version on my 2ds and put all my time there.

I eventually needed more room so I bought a second SD card (16 GB) so I re-downloaded moon and started it up, thinking I could just eventually pokebank my pokemon back over. (Which is where I apparently messed up)

Now when I try to get back on the original save it tells me It doesn't match my "Current save". I called Nintendo and they basically said I'm SOL.

I own a DS and DSi action replay. (If that will help at all) Does anyone here know of a way to get my original save back over transferring the save over the computer ETC? Please I really need help.

Comment: Did you already transfer some of your Pokémon? If they are in your bank they should be able to get put back onto that game you originally had them on. Try using the original SD card, just see if you can work backwards.